# Python - Multithreads for calling the same function to run in parallel and independently

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new in Python and I'm struggling a lot trying to solve a problem. I have three programs running. One of them has the objective to send data, the other to receive and the third one works in the middle (transparently). The difficulty is happening with this third one, which I'm calling delay_loss.py.

It has to emulate delay of packets before delivering them to the receiving program.

Searching a lot I have found a solution (multithreading), which I'm not sure is the best one. Since delay_loss.py can receive a lot of packets "at once" and has to select for each a random time to emulate a delay in the network, I have to be able to send each packet to the receiving program after the random time selected for this packet, independently of the others.

I'm trying to use multithread for this, and I think I'm not using it correctly because all the packets are sent at the same time after some time. The threads seem to not be running the function send_up() independently.

Part of the code of delay_loss.py is shown below:

```
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
...
pool = ThreadPool(window_size)
def send_up (pkt, time_delay, id_pkt):

    time.sleep(time_delay)

    sock_server.sendto(pkt, (C_IP, C_PORT))

def delay_pkt(pkt_recv_raw, rtt, average_delay, id_pkt):

    x = random.expovariate(1/average_delay)          
    time_delay = rtt/(2+x) 

    pool.apply_async(send_up, [pkt_recv_raw, time_delay, id_pkt])

...
delay_pkt(pkt_recv_raw, rtt, average_delay, id_pkt_recv)
id_pkt_recv += 1
```

If anyone has some idea of what am I doing wrong. Or just to say don't take this approach of multithreads for doing this task, it would be of much help!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. I was using the pool without necessity.
It is much simpler to just use the threading.Timer() function, as shown below:

```
t = threading.Timer(time_delay, send_up, [pkt_recv_raw, id_pkt])    
t.start()
```